# Add int to index of 2d list

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

These are my 2 arrays:

```
myList = [
    'AAAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbAbbbbbb', 
    'AbAbbbAbbbbAAAbbbbbbbAbb', 
    'AbAbbbbbbbbAbAAAAbbbbbbb', 
    'AAAbbbbbbbbAbAAbAbbbbbbA', 
    'bbbbbAbbbbbAAAAbAbbbbbbb', 
    'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbAAAbbbbbbb'
]

res = [(0, 0), (1, 11), (2, 13), (3, 0), (4, 11), (5, 14)]
```

res gives the position where you can find `"AAA"` in the array "myList". The 2 numbers in the brackets stand for the Y and X axis(Y as the index and X as the position in the string from the given index.)
My target is it to add 1 to the first number of every bracket. Then I wanna check if at the new positions that I created by adding 1(the next index but same position in string) is the string `"AbA"`. What do  I have to do to achieve this?
Btw sorry for my bad english xD

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly:

```
>>> myList = ['AAAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbAbbbbbb', 'AbAbbbAbbbbAAAbbbbbbbAbb', 'AbAbbbbbbbbAbAAAAbbbbbbb', 'AAAbbbbbbbbAbAAbAbbbbbbA', 'bbbbbAbbbbbAAAAbAbbbbbbb', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbAAAbbbbbbb']
>>> res = [(0, 0), (1, 11), (2, 13), (3, 0), (4, 11), (5, 14)]
>>> [myList[(y+1)%len(myList)][x:x+3] == "AbA" for y,x in res]
[True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Because of the entry `(5, 14)` I've added a modulo to the check, to "loop-around" to the first entry when the `y-index+1` is greater than the length of `myList`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works

Comment: How can I check for these which were true if y+1 is again "AbA" ? And after that how can I check for (these which were true at the second time) if there is "AAA" again?